# Using sort() then set() to get a deduplicated, ordered list not working in Python

Tags: python, string, sorting, set

I'm developing a Python Script who picks up every different word from a txt file and sort them lexicographically.

Here's the script:

```
import re

with open ("test.txt") as f:
  selectedWords =[]
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
      line = re.sub("_", ' ', line) #Different word delimiters
      words=re.findall(r"[\w']+", line.lower())
      for word in words:
          if  re.search(r"[\d']+", word):#delete invalid words such as h2llo
              continue
          else:
              selectedWords.append(word)

selectedWords.sort()
selectedWords=set(selectedWords)
for i in selectedWords:
    print i
f.close()
```

An example input is:

```
to be or not
to
be that is
the q2estion
```

and the expected output is:

```
be
is
not
or
that
the
to
```

Comment: Just what exactly is your question? And doesn't that last line `f.close()` give you an error, since `f` is closed when the `with` construct is ended?

Comment: when you covert something into a set, you will lose the order of the elements, if you want a sorted list of the filtered elements. You want to filter them by creating a set, then convert back to a list (where you can maintain order) and then sort it!

Comment: BTW, in the future, try to make your reproducers **minimal**, as given in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This means, for instance, that if you can get the same problem using a hardcoded list in your program instead of reading from a file, you should take out the file IO. (Likewise, if you can include only pre-parsed words, you should take out the regex parts; etc -- the code in the question should be the smallest possible thing someone else can copy-and-paste to see the same problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're undoing all the work of sorting when you convert to a `set`, because unlike a list, a set is unordered; as they have no ordering, they cannot be either sorted or unsorted.

```
# BROKEN
selectedWords = ['some', 'test', 'data', 'here']
selectedWords.sort()             # this becomes moot
selectedWords=set(selectedWords) # ...because this throws away everything it did.
for i in selectedWords:
    print i
```

...instead:

```
# CORRECT
selectedWords = ['some', 'test', 'data', 'here']
selectedWords=list(set(selectedWords))
selectedWords.sort()
for i in selectedWords:
    print i
```

...or, to keep the data structure as a set, but generate a temporary sorted version and print that:

```
selectedWords = ['some', 'test', 'data', 'here']
selectedWords = set(selectedWords)
for i in sorted(selectedWords):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

set is not sorted, so you cannot use set after you have sorted the data. 
You can do it like this.

```
selectedWords=list(set(selectedWords))
selectedWords.sort()
for i in selectedWords:
    print i
```

Comment: To correctly syntax-highlight a multi-line block, use the `{}` button in the editor or put four spaces before each line, rather than backtick literals.